# Building a FIQL query with peewee

Tags: python, peewee, flask-peewee

I'm attempting to create a function that will take a [FIQL](https://fiql-parser.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#parsing-a-fiql-formatted-string) formatted string and return a [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/index.html) expression.

Let's say I have url params in FIQL format like so:

```
fiql_str = "name==Foo,(country==USA;city==Kansas)"
```

Using a [FIQL Parser](https://fiql-parser.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#parsing-a-fiql-formatted-string) I am able to get this object back:

```
['OR', ('name', '==', 'Foo'), ['AND', ('country', '==', 'USA'), ('city', '==', 'Kansas')]]
```

What I'd like to do, is to create a function that takes the above object, and creates an expression that peewee can understand. I'm used to [django & Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), where I can chain together expressions like so:

```
fm = Q()
for mapping in mappings:
    fm |= Q(subscription__approver=mapping.user)
return self.filter(fm)
```

I've tried mimicking this with peewee's [Query Builder / Node](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#query-builder) like so:

```
def map_to_filter(expressions, node):
    expression = expressions.pop(0)
    if type(expression) == str:
        if expression == "OR":
            node |= map_to_filter(expressions, node)
        if expression == "AND":
            node &= map_to_filter(expressions, node)
    elif type(expression) == tuple:
        return getattr(Store, expression[0]) + expression[1] + expression[2]
    elif type(expression) == list:
        map_to_filter(expression, node)
    return node

result = map_to_filter(expressions, peewee.Node())
```

But I am getting a NotImplementedError:

```
/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py in __sql__(self, ctx)
    616
    617     def __sql__(self, ctx):
--> 618         raise NotImplementedError
    619
    620     @staticmethod

NotImplementedError:
```

Is it possible to build such a function? Otherwise, what other tools/pluggins are available for troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue comes from using a bare `Node`, which does not correspond to any SQL (hence, no **sql** method).

I'd suggest accumulating a list and using `functools.reduce()` to combine them.

e.g.,

```
list_of_conds = [
    (model.field1 == 'val1'),
    (model.field2 == 'bar')]
reduce(operator.and_, list_of_conds)
```

You can switch your reduce function to be operator.or_ where necessary and proceed using a depth-first search, as you have.